# php get sharepoint list items with microsoft graph API

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-list

I've access to a sharepoint list and i want to get the items from it with the graph API

I can view the list items in the browser on this URL:
https://[TENANT_DOMAIN_NAME].sharepoint.com/sites/[SITE_NAME]/Lists/[LIST_NAME]

Created an azure app and setup the authentication with my work microsoft account, installed the msgraph-sdk-php

The authentication is working, i can view the list informations with this endpoint:

/sites/[TENANT_DOMAIN_NAME].sharepoint.com:/sites/[SITE_NAME]:/lists

In the response i can see the specific list, but i don't know how to get the list data from  specific list.

Tried to get it with:

```
/sites/[TENANT_DOMAIN_NAME].sharepoint.com/lists/[LIST_NAME]/items

The specified list was not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the valid endpoint is:

```
/sites/[TENANT_DOMAIN].sharepoint.com:/sites/[SITE_NAME]:/lists/[LIST_NAME]/items?expand=fields
```